# Water dropping from radiator without boiling or engine overheating

Tags: radiator, pump, water

I observed oil in my ford mondeo and it was diagonized as to gasket issue. This was replaced. After which my mechanic noticed the car was somewhat over heating so my rewire had to set the fan on high. we observed that the car does not show any sign of overheating from dashboard not the water boils from radiator instead water drops from the radiator.
What could be the possible cause and solution

Comment: Check for cracked radiator with a leak down test??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!